# Changing the BackColor of control based on parent after drop

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi Im trying to change the `BackColor` of a `Panel` after is has been dropped into a `FlowLayoutPanel`. There are several `FlowLayoutPanels`, i would like to change the  `BackColor` of the `Panel` depending on whichever FLP it is in.

Code:

```
    private void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = sender as Control;
        this.DoDragDrop(control.Name, DragDropEffects.Move);
        //Here i change the colour.
        control.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 232, 232);
    }

    private void panel_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
            return;

        var name = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string)) as string;
        var control = this.Controls.Find(name, true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (control != null)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }
    }

    private void panel_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
            return;

        var name = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string)) as string;
        var control = this.Controls.Find(name, true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (control != null)
        {
            control.Parent.Controls.Remove(control);
            var panel = sender as FlowLayoutPanel;
            ((FlowLayoutPanel)sender).Controls.Add(control);
            control.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 232, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle [`ControlAdded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controladded(v=vs.110).aspx) event of your `FlowLayoutPanel` controls and set the desired color for dropped control there. For example:

```
private void flowLayoutPanel2_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.BackColor = Color.Red;
}

private void flowLayoutPanel1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

Also you can apply such logic in `panel_DragDrop` based on panel name. For example:

```
control.Parent.Controls.Remove(control);
var panel = sender as FlowLayoutPanel;
((FlowLayoutPanel)sender).Controls.Add(control);
if(panel.Name == "flowLayoutPanel1")
    control.BackColor = Color.Blue;
else
    control.BackColor = Color.Red;
```